# Smarty PHP won't show assigns or $sessions

Tags: php, session, smarty

I am wanting to user the users session id in a url, however for some reason smarty PHP won't return any of the session values.

I am wondering if there is something I need to do before I can print the following in a tpl file:

```
{$smarty.session.id}
{$userid}
```

I have tried to put both of those into my tpl file; however they won't show, once the page is loaded.

```
$smarty->assign('userid', ''.$_SESSION['userid']);
```

My template file

```
{*********************************************************
  Multi line comment block with credits block
  @ author:                    harrower.xyz
  @ Site:                      SIITE.XYZ
  @ Date Created               11/06/2016
  @ Last Edited                07/01/2017
  @ Orginially Created By      Russell Harrower
  @ Edited By                  Russell Harrower
  @ maintainer:                russell@site.xyz
  **********************************************************}

  {* The header file with the main logo and stuff  *}
  {extends file='./tpl-files/template.tpl'}
{block name=head}
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function (){
    hidestuff("entermanually");

  }
        function addEvent(obj, event, func) {
             if (obj.addEventListener) {
                 obj.addEventListener(event, func, false);
                 return true;
             } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
                 obj.attachEvent('on' + event, func);
             } else {
                 var f = obj['on' + event];
                 obj['on' + event] = typeof f === 'function' ? function() {
                     f();
                     func();
                 } : func
             }
         }
         //SHOW AND HIDE DATA FROM USERS
         function showstuff(boxid){
            document.getElementById(boxid).style.display="block";
            componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
         }

         function hidestuff(boxid){
            document.getElementById(boxid).style.display="none";
         }
         function manuallyenterdata(){
           hidestuff("RAU");
           hidestuff("fb");
           showstuff("entermanually");

        }
  </script>
  <script src="plugins/stepper/stepper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="plugins/dropzone/dropzone.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/dropzone/dropzone.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='templates/main/style/newprofile.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script>


    // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
      console.log('statusChangeCallback');
      console.log(response);
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
      // app know the current login status of the person.
      // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
      // for FB.getLoginStatus().
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // Logged into your app and Facebook.
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
      //  alert(accessToken);
        testAPI();
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
          'into this app.';
      } else {
        // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
        // they are logged into this app or not.
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
          'into Facebook.';
      }
    }
    // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
    // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
    // code below.
    function checkLoginState() {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);

      });
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxx',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                          // the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v2.6' // use graph api version 2.5
    });

    // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
    // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
    // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
    // the callback you provide.  They can be:
    //
    // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
    // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
    // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
    //    your app or not.
    //
    // These three cases are handled in the callback function.



    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "facebook_login",true);
      //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(response));

    });

    };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
    // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
    function testAPI() {
      console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
      FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,birthday,picture,cover,email,about', function(response) {

//                  alert(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
        console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.first_name  + ' ' + response.last_name  + '\n ' + response.birthday + '\n ' + response.email +'\n ' + response.cover.source + '\n '+ response.picture.data.url +'\n '+ response.about);
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "facebook_profile",true);
        //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(response));


        //window.location.replace("facebook.php");
//                  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
//                  'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + ' - '+ response.email + '!'+ ' - '+ response.gender;
      });


    }

  </script>
{/block}
{block name=body}
<div class="mdl-section__centre mdl-grid mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col" style="margin-bottom:0 !important;">
<div class="mdl-card-fullwide mdl-shadow--0dp">

  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">

    <div class="mdl-stepper-horizontal-alternative">
      <div class="mdl-stepper-step active-step editable-step">
        <div class="mdl-stepper-circle"><span>1</span></div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-title">Basic Information</div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-bar-left"></div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-bar-right"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-stepper-step active-step">
        <div class="mdl-stepper-circle"><span>2</span></div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-title">Contact Information</div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-optional"></div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-bar-left"></div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-bar-right"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-stepper-step">
        <div class="mdl-stepper-circle"><span>3</span></div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-title">Your Pets</div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-optional"></div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-bar-left"></div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-bar-right"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-stepper-step">
        <div class="mdl-stepper-circle"><span>4</span></div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-title">Share</div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-optional">Optional</div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-bar-left"></div>
        <div class="mdl-stepper-bar-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>


  <div id="RAU" class="mdl-card-fullwide mdl-card">
    <div class="mdl-card__title">
      <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Your Profile Information</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-grid mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
      {$smarty.session.uid}
    </div>
    <div id="fb" class="mdl-section__centre mdl-grid mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col" style="margin-bottom:0;">
          <fb:login-button size="large" scope="public_profile,email,user_birthday,user_location" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
            Fetch My Facebook Information
          </fb:login-button>
    </div>

          <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
          <div id="manualprofile" class="mdl-section__centre mdl-grid mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col" style="margin-bottom:0;">
            <button onClick="manuallyenterdata()" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
              Don't link my Facebook {$smarty.session.id}
            </button>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="entermanually" class="mdl-card-fullwide mdl-card">
  <div class="mdl-card__title">
    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Upload a Profile Picture</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-grid mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
  </div>


    <div class="mdl-grid mdl-cell mdl-cell--11-col">
      <!-- Simple Textfield -->
          <div class="mdl-grid">
            <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
              <div id="profile" class="dropzone">
              </div>

          </div>
        </div>


  <!--  <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
      <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        Get Started
      </a>
    </div>-->
    <!--<div class="mdl-card__menu">
      <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <i class="material-icons">share</i>
      </button>
    </div>-->
  </div>
<div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
    <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" style="float:right;">
      Next Step
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

  </div>
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">

    var mydrop = new Dropzone("div#profile", {
      url: "https://site.xyz/v1/users/post",

         paramName: "file",
         maxFiles : 1,
         uploadMultiple: false,
         addRemoveLinks : false,
         acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
         autoProcessQueue: true,
         init: function() {
       var submitButton = document.querySelector("#act-on-upload")
       myDropzone = this;
       submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
           myDropzone.processQueue();
       });
       myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
           if (!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
               if(file.type.match(/application.zip/)){
                   myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", file, "path/to/img");
               } else {
                   myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", file, "path/to/img");
               }
           }
       });
       myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
           myDropzone.removeFile(file);
       });
   },
    });

    console.log( mydrop.dropzone );

</script>
{/literal}

{/block}
```

Comment: Have you started a session in your php file using [`session_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) or [`session.auto_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) in php.ini? The `$_SESSION` global isn't available unless you've started a session. Can you post your whole PHP file?

Comment: in the index.php, I used session_start - is there a better way to do it?

Comment: If you dump out `$_SESSION['userid']` in your php file do you get the correct value? `var_dump($_SESSION['userid']);exit;`